# Compile- vs run-time const variable assignment and allocation of vlas in C++

Tags: c++, templates, constants, variable-length-array

I was working on a template function with non-type parameters (to avoid dynamic allocation of arrays) when a number of questions arose. My first question regards compile-time variable assignment. This arose from the following attempts at calls to the template function:

```c
template<int n>
int *getDegrees(int A[][n]) {
  //return degrees
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int n = 10;
  int A[n][n];
  int *degs = getDegrees<n>(A);
}
```

Here, we have two errors: first, the compiler is unable to resolve the call to `getDegrees(A)`:

```c
main.cc:27: error: no matching function for call to ‘getDegrees(int [(((long unsigned int)(((long int)n) + -0x00000000000000001)) + 1)][(((long unsigned int)(((long int)n) + -0x00000000000000001)) + 1)])’
```

Second, we're unable to use `n` in the template call as it isn't a constant expression. Simply making `n` constant does resolve the issues

```c
const int n = 10;
```

however, if I were to do

```c
int m = 10;
const int n = m;
```

we get the same errors. While the second assignment may be allowed by the compiler, is it considered bad form to do so? Additionally, why would making `n` constant make a difference in resolving the function call?

My other question regards vlas: is memory allocated for them on the stack or the heap (and is this compiler-dependent)? There appears to have been some controversy in even allowing them in C++, should they be avoided in favor of vectors (or similar containers)?

Appreciate any insight!

Comment: VLAs aren't C++.  Do you want C answers?

Comment: Interesting, my GNU C++ compiler has no problems with vlas, I wasn't aware they were a C construct. C answers would be fine though, thanks for the heads-up!

Comment: If you want dynamic stack allocation, you can always try alloca().

Comment: If vlas are allocated dynamically on the stack, then g++ appears to do so without needing an explicit call to alloca().

Comment: @glinka: While the compiler allows VLAs in C++, they are not arrays in the same sense that regular arrays. Their type is not fully known at compile time (the size is part of the type in C++), and thus they cannot be used in templates.

Answer (score 5):

I will try to answer whatever I could get from your question.
You can change the function prototype to receive the array by reference:

```
template<size_t n> // see the type
int *getDegrees(int (&A)[n][n]) {  // see the signature
  // ...
}
```

In above code, we are leveraging the fact that the array has same dimensions.
However, in general case it should be:

```
template<size_t n1, size_t n2> // see the type
int *getDegrees(int (&A)[n1][n2]) {  // see the signature
  // ...
}
```

If the size is too big then an error is issued by the compiler to inform you. e.g. (from g++):

> error: size of array ‘A’ is too large

Now coming to the other question regarding the difference between assignment of the constant integer.
In C++, the array size has to be compile time constant and

```
const int n = 10;
```

fulfills that requirement. Because the compiler can make out that, 10 is a literal number being assigned to `n`.

In case of,

```
int m = 10;
const int n = m;
```

Compiler finds out that the source of `n` is *not* a compile time constant itself. And thus it makes the code ill formed.

Comment: While ill-formed, n appears to behave as expected (it is assigned the unchangeable value of 10). Should such constructs nonetheless be avoided?

Comment: @glinka: G++ has a nonconforming extension allowing VLAs (arrays whos bounds are not compile time constant), but even G++ requires template parameters to be compile time constants.  I'd avoid them.